# The name does not exist in the namespace but intellisense says it does

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I would like to use a class that inherits from `UserControl` in the xaml designer, but for some reason it doesn't see the class. I tried removing all the code I could and simplifying things, but it still won't work. The class is

```
namespace StationHouse
{
    public class TryMe : UserControl {}
}
```

My xaml looks like

```
<MyTypes:TryMe x:Class="StationHouse.Operations.Contact"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:MyTypes="clr-namespace:StationHouse"
```

But I get the error:

> The name "TryMe" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:StationHouse"

Even stranger, if I go into the main section of the xaml and type `MyTypes:` then intellisense pops up `TryMe`, but once I select it I still get the same error. I've tried rebuilding the application and closing/reopening Visual Studio, but no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could make sure that both assemblies target the same .NET framework. I've had issues like this when one assembly was .NET 4 and the other was .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm sure there are a number of things that can cause this issue, my particular cause was related to the compiler. Basically, I changed some implementation from an Interface to an abstract class, which generated a ton of compiler errors. When I went through to change my xaml to reference the correct, new class, I guess the background compiler was having trouble recognizing it as a valid class because of all the errors.

What I did was comment out several things, which finally allowed me to compile my new abstract class and have my above error disappear. Then I uncommented things one by one and moved them over without issue.